# Php Mysql Group by similer 2 fields?

Tags: php, group-by, while-loop

```
$query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
              "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
              "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ". 
              "GROUP BY bill.date , bill.agent_id  ".
              "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";
```

Table Structure : https://i.stack.imgur.com/38tKh.jpg

Current Result

```
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
|         |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
| Agent 1 | 35 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 | 10 |  0 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 1 |  0 |  0 | 12 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 3 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100 |  0 |
| Agent 6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 | 14 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

But I want To get Like The Following

```
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
|         |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
| Agent 1 | 35 |  0 | 12 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 | 10 |  0 |   0 | 14 |
| Agent 3 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100 |  0 |
| Agent 6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  0 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

Php Code

```
<?php 

    $query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
              "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
              "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ". 
              "GROUP BY bill.date , bill.agent_id  ".
              "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";

    $result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die('Error, query failed1'); 
    if  (mysql_num_rows($result4)>0){
    mysql_data_seek($result4, 0);   

?>
  <?php while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
  <?php $date =    $row4['date'];

    $var = $date;
    $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($var) );
    $date=substr($date, 0, -8); 

    echo $date;

    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row4['name']; ?></td>

    <td><?php if ($date == 01) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 02) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 03) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 04) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 05) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 06) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 07) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 08) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 09) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($date == 10) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the ***Group By*** part:

Try this Query:

```
$query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total,
bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
"FROM bill, bill_agents ".
"WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ". 
"GROUP BY DATE(bill.date) , bill.agent_id ".
"ORDER BY bill.date ASC";
```

Comment: with both query its generating same result